# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} $

Tags: limits

How to find

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} $$

Comment: Do you know L'Hôpital's rule? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: How do you define $\sin x$?

Comment: @user79202: If user79249 knows the general formula for the derivative of $\sin$, hopefully they can also recognize $\sin'(0)$ here.

Answer (score 4):

The proof that this limit is $1$ can be found in most calculus textbooks. It’s also available online, e.g., [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofTrigDeriv.aspx) and [here](http://web.mit.edu/wwmath/calculus/limits/trig.html).